# PreparedStatement to update one value based on another in a record

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have below table structure

```
id  msg  keyword
-----------------
1   abc    ?
2   xyz    ?
```

The above is just an example; however my real table looks like that only. Based on the value of msg field, I need to call an API that would calculate the keywords from the msg and then update the particular record. How can I get the record and update as well, at the same time using Java PreparedStatement?
Also since my database is very large, what would be the efficient way to do it? Below is the code snippet  :

```
public void updateColumns() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;
            String query = "select * from '" + Constants.tableName + "'";

            // How to uypdate the record here by calling my custom API that reads the msg and returns the keywords in the message??
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic JDBC solution would be to generate a batch update :

```
String select = "SELECT id, msg FROM my_table";
String update = "UPDATE my_table SET keyword = ? WHERE id = ?";
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(update);) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        ps.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
        ps.setString(2, MyAPI.calculateKeyword(rs.getString(2));
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
}
```

Of course, if you table is very large, you may which to consider every X rows.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I need to do this in batches,I will need to set the batch size. Since I have to execute the two queries simulatneously, will the batch be able to do both in the same batch of records? 

Also in the above code snippet: {
ps.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
ps.setString(2, MyAPI.calculateKeyword(rs.getString(2));}

Should it not be
{
ps.setInt(2, rs.getInt(2));
        ps.setString(1, MyAPI.calculateKeyword(rs.getString(1));
}